# How do I add a space after the 'Part#' on the product page in Magento website?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

[Please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbHmD.jpg)

I want to add a space between the 'part#' and part number.

Where should I go to find the proper file?
My magento version is 1.9.2.4

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that there is stackexchange for magento! Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your theme. I have 3 sites with 3 different themes and the 'part#' is found in

```
app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

if you cant find it there then you can always go to your admin 
and go to system > Configuration

select the store view and go to Developer > Debug

set "Template Path Hints" to yes and click save.

Then go to your front end and you will see which file that information is being echo form.